# Fluent API and Entity Framework - Composite Foreign key with Literal value

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have looked all through this site and have been banging my head to resolve a seemingly simple question with EF and Fluent API.   I've tried to fit some of the answers to my problem to no avail so my apologies in advance.

I am using VS2013 and C#.   I have the following model defined:

```
[Table("party")]
public class Party
{    
  [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  [Column(Order = 0)]
  [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
  public long party_id { get; set; }

  [Key]
  [Column(Order = 1)]
  [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
  public string party_type { get; set; }
}
```

I have another model like this:

```
[Table("person")]
public class Person
{
  [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
  public long person_id { get; set; }

  public virtual Party party { get; set; }
}
```

The PERSON model needs to be foreign key linked to the PARTY.  The "party_type" column holds a constant string of the base-type of party being added with incrementing values on "party_id".   Meaning I could have:

Party_ID    Party_Type
1           person
2           person
1           company
1           org
2           company
3           person

How do I in FLUENT API connect the PERSON model to the PARTY model based on the "person_id" column and a constant of "person"?

Thanks and help!

John